# How can I use the same Exchange session state information multiple times in a runspace pool?

Tags: multithreading, powershell, exchange-server, session-state, runspace

I'm trying to create a multithreaded script entirely for the benefit of speed, the synchronous version I've written works but is slow. I've hit a wall where because each thread is importing Exchange session information, it's as slow or slower than the synchronous code, especially as the server count increases.

I'm sure there is a better way and I believe the proper way to do this would be to load the pssession one time and attach it to the runspace pool, but in my searching I cannot find a working example of how to do this with Exchange?

Below is my asynchronous vs synchronous comparison. Runtime for the asynchronous code was 12:41, and for the synchronous code was 15:02.

```
cls
$stopWatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew();
[DateTime]::Now.ToString();




    # Fill in these two values
$connectionUri = "http://[something]/powershell";   
$servers = @("server1","server2","server3","server4","server5","server6","server7","server8","server9","server10","server11","server12");
    # /fill




# asynchronous
Write-Host "Asynchronous";

# Create session state

$myString = "this is session state!";
$sessionState = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState]::CreateDefault();
$sessionstate.Variables.Add((New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.SessionStateVariableEntry -ArgumentList "myString" ,$myString, "example string"));

# Create runspace pool consisting of $numThreads runspaces
$minimumAmountOfThreads = 1;
$maximumAmountOfThreads= 15;
$RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool($minimumAmountOfThreads, $maximumAmountOfThreads, $sessionState, $Host);
$RunspacePool.Open();


$threads = @();
$Jobs = @();
$asynchronousThreadCount = 0;
[int]$index = 0;
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    $scriptBlock = "import-pssession (new-pssession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $connectionUri) -AllowClobber; `$returnValue = @(); `$returnValue += Get-ExchangeServer -Identity $server; `$returnValue += Get-MailboxDatabase -Server $server; `$returnValue += Get-MailboxDatabase -Server $server -status; return `$returnValue;"; # working

    $asynchronousThreadCount ++;
    $runspaceObject = [PSCustomObject] @{
        Runspace = [PowerShell]::Create()
        Invoker = $null
    }
    $runspaceObject.Runspace.RunSpacePool = $runspacePool;
    $runspaceObject.Runspace.AddScript($scriptBlock) | Out-Null;
    $runspaceObject.Runspace.AddArgument($server) | Out-Null;
    $runspaceObject.Invoker = $runspaceObject.Runspace.BeginInvoke();
    $threads += $runspaceObject;
    $elapsed = $StopWatch.Elapsed;

    Write-Host "Asynchronous created thread $asynchronousThreadCount " $elapsed;
    $index++;
}

Write-Host $threads.Count;
Write-Host "";
Write-Host "Waiting.." -NoNewline;
Do {
   Write-Host "." -NoNewline;
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 1;
} While ( $runspaceObject.Invoker.IsCompleted -contains $false ); 

$resultsAsynchronous = @();

foreach ($tr in $threads)
{
    $resultsAsynchronous += $tr.Runspace.EndInvoke($tr.Invoker);
    $tr.Runspace.Dispose();
}

$runspacePool.Close();
$runspacePool.Dispose();    

$elapsed = $StopWatch.Elapsed;
Write-Host "";
Write-Host "Multithread elapsed time: $elapsed";
Write-Host "Asynchronous return value count " $resultsAsynchronous.Count;

Write-Host "";
Write-Host "";
Write-Host "";







# synchronous
Write-Host "Synchronous";

$StopWatch.Reset | Out-Null;
import-pssession (new-pssession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $connectionUri) -AllowClobber;
$resultsSynchronous = @();
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    $resultsSynchronous += Get-ExchangeServer -Identity $server; 
    $resultsSynchronous += Get-MailboxDatabase -Server $server; 
    $resultsSynchronous += Get-MailboxDatabase -Server $server -status;
}

$elapsed = $StopWatch.Elapsed;
Write-Host "";
Write-Host "Single thread elapsed time: $elapsed";
Write-Host "Synchronous return value count " $resultsSynchronous.Count;
```

Comment: Have you tried the synchronous method with `-AsJob` switch? You can use `Get-Job` to monitor the tasks. Because the commands are imported they are just going to be slow. There are ways to import objects and variables into runspaces, but as you are aware, working with runspaces get complex very quickly.
If you are intent on using runspaces, @boeprox has a [method for you in his blog](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/04/19/sharing-variables-and-live-objects-between-powershell-runspaces/) that I have used that as a guide for threading jobs several times, although not with imported pssessions.

Comment: Thanks for reply @brendan62269 , after studying the link you've provided (thank you for that) if I understand correctly, I believe his examples are for sharing return values within the hash table. Maybe I'm missing it, but how could I share the importeded session with the .setVariable command? Maybe with the sessionState.Modules.Add() command? Even though I don't believe a possession is considered a module?

Comment: Maybe that isn't the right way either. Have you tried resolving the session first then using it as an argument? I don't have enough space in a comment to give an example. so I'll write it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The synchronized list wasn't really what I had in mind, either, just passing the live session in as an argument should work. Resolve the session before the loop:

```
$importSession = new-pssession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $connectionUri
```

Do your foreach and then add params to your script block and an additionak argument for the session to import:

```
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    $scriptBlock = {
        param( $importSession, $server )
        import-pssession $importSession
        Get-ExchangeServer -Identity $server
        Get-MailboxDatabase -Server $server
        Get-MailboxDatabase -Server $server -status
    }

    $asynchronousThreadCount++;
    $runspaceObject = [PSCustomObject] @{
        Runspace = [PowerShell]::Create()
        Invoker = $null
    }
    $runspaceObject.Runspace.RunSpacePool = $runspacePool;
    $runspaceObject.Runspace.AddScript($scriptBlock) | Out-Null;
    $runspaceObject.Runspace.AddArgument($importSession) | Out-Null;
    $runspaceObject.Runspace.AddArgument($server) | Out-Null;
    $runspaceObject.Invoker = $runspaceObject.Runspace.BeginInvoke();
    $threads += $runspaceObject;
    $elapsed = $StopWatch.Elapsed;

    Write-Host "Asynchronous created thread $asynchronousThreadCount " $elapsed;
    $index++;
}
```

I can't verify that'll work, but I think not having to do the new-pssession to http://[something]/powershell each time is likely to reduce the load time per thread significantly.